# Showing the following set is a $\sigma$ algebra. Proof verification.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $M$ be an infinite $\sigma$ algebra on X. Show that if $A \in M$, then the collection $M_A$={$B \cap A: B \in M$} is a $\sigma$ algebra on A.

My thoughts/attempt (Really struggling)

To show $M_A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, I need to show that $M_A$ is closed under complements and countable unions.
I'm really confused on how to show either but here is my attempt anyways.

First I show finite unions:

Let $B_1 \cap A$ $\in M_A$ and $B_2 \cap A$ $\in M_A$ (thus $A$, $B_1$ and $B_2 \in M$).

$(B_1 \cap A)$ $\cup$  $(B_2 \cap A)$=($B_1 \cup B_2)$ $\cap$  $A$ $\in M_A$ $(B_1 \cup B_2 \in M$ as M is a $\sigma$ algebra). Thus we closed under finite union. Can do the same process to show for countable union.

Second: I show closure under complements:

Let $B_1 \cap A$ $\in M_A$. Need to show that $(B_1 \cap A)$$^{c}$ $\in$ $M_A$.

I can write $(B_1 \cap A)$$^{c}$ = ($B_1 \cap A^C$) $\cup$ ($B_1^C \cap A$).

$B_1 \cap A^C \in M_A$ as $A^c \in M$ as $M$ is a $\sigma$ algebra. $B_1^c \cap A \in M_A$ as $B_1^c \in M$ as $M$ is a $\sigma$ algebra.
Thus, $(B_1 \cap A)$$^{c}$ $\in M_A$ as it is the union of two things in $M_A$ and we previously showed that $M_A$ is closed under finite union.
Is my proof correct? Or am I very off in my approach? Thank you.

Comment: I think your approach is sound, you just need to make sure you get the countable union case right. But as you say,  it's essentially the same as the finite case.

Comment: $(B_1 \cap A^C) \cap A = \emptyset$

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that $B_1 \cap A^C \not\subset A$ **!**, so $B_1 \cap A^C \notin M_A$.
The complement should be found in $A$, so the complement in $A$ for $B_1 \cap A$ is $B_1^C \cap A$.

Comment: So the complement of B1 intersection A is B1 complement intersection A and this entity is in Ma as B1 complement is in M as M is a sigma algebra?

Comment: Also is the union part ok? or is it just the complements I need to fix? How do I show that the complement of ($B_1$ $\cap$ A is $B_1^c \cap A$ or is this just by construction (what I'm thinking)?

Comment: It is by construction. you are looking for complements in $A$, not in $X$